# issue with WiFi Ubuntu Mate

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

Good morning everyone,

I am having troubles connecting to my WiFi.  I have installed Ubuntu Mate 22.04.
I have been having this problem since a while, but recently it became worse.
Before, my wireless connection would drop now and then, and my device wouldn't be able to find any wireless connection, and the switch "Enable wifi" in the network tab would disappear.  This wouldn't be a frequent issue, though, and I used to restart my computer to have my network back.
Now this issue became more frequent.  Apart from this, the features of it are the same.

I post my outputs for the commands in Ubuntu's troubleshoot page:

```
beoebdue@beoebdue-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ nmcli
usb0: connected to Wired connection 2
        "LG LM-X420xxx/G2 Android Phone"
        ethernet (rndis_host), 56:DB:36:EE:F0:21, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.42.180/24
        route4 192.168.42.0/24 metric 100
        route4 default via 192.168.42.129 metric 100
        inet6 fe80::e58e:c589:1d94:5c24/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

docker0: connected (externally) to docker0
        "docker0"
        bridge, 02:42:F9:E6:ED:DA, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 172.17.0.1/16
        route4 172.17.0.0/16 metric 0
        route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000

C8:F3:19:AA:EB:E2: disconnected
        "K20"
        1 connection available
        bt (bluez), C8:F3:19:AA:EB:E2, hw

wlo1: disconnected
        "Intel Wireless-AC 3168NGW"
        2 connections available
        wifi (iwlwifi), 68:EC:C5:43:AD:AA, autoconnect, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlo1: disconnected
        "p2p-dev-wlo1"
        wifi-p2p, hw

eno1: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), 10:E7:C6:A7:C9:24, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.42.129

        servers: 192.168.42.129

        servers: 192.168.42.129

        servers: 192.168.42.129
        interface: usb0

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.

beoebdue@beoebdue-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for beoebdue: 
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 10:e7:c6:a7:c9:24
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-72-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 68:ec:c5:43:ad:aa
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-72-generic firmware=29.198743027.0 3168-29.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 memory:b1000000-b1001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: a
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 56:db:36:ee:f0:21
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-72-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.180 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

I think that can be useful to know that, when my wifi doesn't work, I have:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

But, when my wifi works (as now), I have:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"FRITZ!Box 7520 GC"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.58 GHz  Access Point: 2C:91:AB:A5:6C:40   
          Bit Rate=325 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:30   Missed beacon:0
```

Is there anyone who can explain me how should I interpret this result, and how to fix it to have a stable wifi connection?

Thank you in advance.  I will edit my answer as I have any update, or by request!